# can't orderBy accessor in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sql-order-by, accessor

I cant orderBy points. Points is accessor.

Controller:

```
$volunteers = $this->volunteerFilter();
$volunteers = $volunteers->orderBy('points')->paginate(10);
```

Volunteers Model:

```
public function siteActivities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(VolunteerEvent::class, 'volunteer_event_user', 'volunteer_id', 'volunteer_event_id')
        ->withPivot('data', 'point', 'point_reason');
}

public function getPointsAttribute(){
    $totalPoint = 0;
    $volunteerPoints = $this->siteActivities->pluck('pivot.point', 'id')->toArray() ?? [];
    foreach ($volunteerPoints as $item) {
        $totalPoint += $item;
    }

    return $totalPoint;
}
```

But I try to `sortyByDesc('points')` in view it works but doesn't work true. Because `paginate(10)` is `limit(10)`. So it doesn't sort for all data, sort only 10 data.

Then I try to use datatable/yajra. It works very well but I have much data. so the problem came out

> Error code: Out of Memory

Comment: `orderBy` is a database query directive, your accessor is something that exists only on your laravel project... you will have to find a way to descrive that accessor using laravel query builder raw for example

Comment: i understand , but my query is long. i cant write 'query builder raw'

Comment: $this->volunteerFilter(); this class is long

Comment: Could you please add your code as text so that the question is still understandable even if the image gets deleted?

Answer (score 0):

You could aggregate the column directly in the query

```
$volunteers = $this->volunteerFilter();
$volunteers = $volunteers->selectRaw('SUM(pivot.points) AS points)')->orderByDesc('points')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Oh, you have to replace `pivot` with the actual name of your pivot table. Sorry for that.

Comment: $volunteers = Volunteer::with(['_region', 'siteActivities'])
                      ->selectRaw('SUM(volunteer_event_user.point) AS points)')
        ->orderByDesc('points')->paginate(10);